# Applications of Combinatorial Games in Computational Biology

Tags: ds.algorithms, gt.game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, bioinformatics

I'm looking for general references in the literature about applications of games algorithmics in computational biology.

**Q1.** What are the notable cases of computational-biology or bioinformatics problems that can be modeled/analyzed by means of ***combinatorial*** games ?

**Q2.** What are the notable cases of computational-biology or bioinformatics problems that can be modeled/analyzed by means of ***economic*** games ?

Comment: Do you only want comp-bio and binf, or biology more broadly? I.e. Evolutionary biology, molecular biology, systems bio, etc. what about things like ecology?

Comment: Also, a closely related question: [Ecology and evolution through the algorithmic lens](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14103/1037)

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for reply, yes to know new references about applications of games in biology "more broadly" would be very interesting..